# Stopping Jquery displaying an img if the validation isn't passed with PHP or Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, validation

Ok, so I created an ajax add to cart with Jquery. Basically on click of a button the data is passed to a php page, using jquery and then returns data which is turned into variables and the item is added to the cart, the cart is popped up and a 'item added to cart' image is displayed as confirmation. Anyway... this all works perfectly.

This is my Jquery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#qtyform").validationEngine({promptPosition : "topLeft:0,15", scroll: false});
    //Examples of how to assign the ColorBox event to elements

    $("#cartbtn").click(function () {
        //$('.addcartform').submit();
        $("#cbox").stop(true,false).animate({right:  0}, 500);
        Qty=document.qtyform.Qty.value;
        ProductID=document.qtyform.ProductID.value;
        CatID=document.qtyform.CatID.value;
        Price=document.qtyform.Price.value;
        <?php if(isset($_GET['cart'])) {?>
        itemid=document.qtyform.itemid.value;
        <?php }elseif(isset($_GET['del'])){ ?> 
        itemid2=document.qtyform.itemid2.value;
        <?php } ?>
        //$('#cartresult').load("process.php?Qty="+Qty+"&ProductID="+ProductID+"&CatID="+CatID+"&Price="+Price<?php if(isset($_GET['cart'])) {?>+"&itemid="+itemid<?php }else if (isset($_GET['del'])){ ?>+"&itemid2="+itemid2<?php } ?>);

        $.get("process.php?Qty="+Qty+"&ProductID="+ProductID+"&CatID="+CatID+"&Price="+Price<?php if(isset($_GET['cart'])) {?>+"&itemid="+itemid<?php }else if (isset($_GET['del'])){ ?>+"&itemid2="+itemid2<?php } ?>, function(data) {
         //alert("Data = "+data);
         mydata = data; 
         var mytext = mydata.split('#');

        var message = mytext[0];
        var linkto = mytext[1];
        var hreftext = mytext[2];
        var finalQty = mytext[3];

        $('#cartresult').html('<span style="margin:0px 0px 0px 30px"><img src="images/ajax-loader-cart.gif" width="24" height="24" alt="" /></span>');

        document.getElementById('cartresult').innerHTML = '<br /><a href="'+linkto+'">'+hreftext+'</a>';
        document.getElementById('cartnum').innerHTML = finalQty;

        });
    });
});
```

Now the problem is:

```
$("#qtyform").validationEngine({promptPosition : "topLeft:0,15", scroll: false});
```

The line above using Jquery inline validation to validate a input box for Quantity. If the value entered isn't numeric, it doesn't get added to the cart. This also works, but the added to cart image is still displayed. I would like to stop this. The line for adding the image is this one:

```
$('#cartresult').html('<span style="margin:0px 0px 0px 30px"><img src="images/ajax-loader-cart.gif" width="24" height="24" alt="" /></span>');
```

Can anyone suggest a way in Jquery or PHP to check if the value entered is numeric, or someway to stop the image being displayed if nothing has been added to the basket. I am fairly new to Jquery but can figure it out, I am stronger with PHP. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You mean

```
if (message.indexOf("error") !=-1) { alert('Nope'); return false;} 
else {
    $('#cartresult').html('<span style="margin:0px 0px 0px 30px"><img src="images/ajax-loader-cart.gif" width="24" height="24" alt="" /></span>');

    document.getElementById('cartresult').innerHTML = '<br /><a href="'+linkto+'">'+hreftext+'</a>';
    document.getElementById('cartnum').innerHTML = finalQty;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, i'm sure by your reputation its the correct code, but even though the input box is full of letters, the img is still displayed, although nothing is getting added to the cart. I am maybe not explaining it properly.

Comment: I am assuming you send something back with the word error in the message.

Comment: All that gets sent back is a string seperated by #'s, then split into variables as you can see. the word error never appears, it is just that there will be a different message depending on where the user has come from add/update basket. If that makes sense

Comment: But how will you tell the script that the PHP failed ?